# Determine closest ancestor between list of classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop, inheritance

Consider this example:

```
class Point {}
class Point2D extends Point {}
class Point3D extends Point2D {}
class FloatPoint extends Point {}

class Bar {}
class Foo extends Bar {}

const result = joinWithClosestAncestor([Point, Point2D, Point3D, FloatPoint, Bar, Foo])
// result === [[Point], [Point2D, Point], [Point3D, Point2D], [FloatPoint, Point], [Bar], [Foo, Bar]];
```

I'm trying to create `joinWithClosestAncestor` which takes an array of classes and returns an array of pairs where the first element is the class & the second is the closest ancestor of the class (if any) from the input classes.

In the example `Point3D` is derived from `Point` through `Point2D`, but because `Point2D` is in the input list & is closer related to `Point3D` than `Point`, it is instead chosen. I can use `Class.prototype instanceof X` to determine if it's related or not but I can't compare the `depth` of the relation.

Is there a way to somehow compare the `depth` of `instanceof` between different classes to always get the CLOSEST relation? Or any other way?

Comment: Seems a lot like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) on a class constructor to get its immediate superclass constructor.  It can't find an obvious MDN source, but [*JavaScript for Impatient Programmers* by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_proto-chains-classes.html#subclasses-under-the-hood-advanced) explains that this happens so that `static` properties and methods are inherited by subclasses.

Anyway, since you can find the immediate superclass constructor, you can walk up that chain until you find something that exists in your array or until you walk off the end of the chain.  Something like this, for example:

```
function joinWithClosestAncestor(ctors: Array<new (...args: any) => any>) {
  const ret = [];
  for (let ctor of ctors) {
    const cur = [ctor];
    ret.push(cur);
    for (
      let parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(ctor);
      parent;
      parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(parent)
    ) {
      if (ctors.includes(parent)) {
        cur.push(parent);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

It produces the result you were looking for, at least for the example you gave:

```
const result = joinWithClosestAncestor([Point, Point2D, Point3D, FloatPoint, Bar, Foo])
console.log(JSON.stringify(result.map(x => x.map(y => y.name))));
// [["Point"],["Point2D","Point"],["Point3D","Point2D"],
//  ["FloatPoint","Point"],["Bar"],["Foo","Bar"]]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKD2BLAdgF2gb2gXwLAChRIYEVUAmAEWgFMAPVG5AExKTUxwKKjndQDM1eoxZsyVTnkLheAMRDwwqUhxFNWfMlO6yYAITAAnHTOLQ58eLQYaDx0wQBmAV2TBUieMmgArdgDqiKgAFgDCihA0EKgAgu7RqPBGABQeyRAAXNCxRkZgAJ4APMg0AO7QKQB0NcYA5lnQYMgFAJTQALwAfE0tXe0YBNDQwN4x0EY06B3QANoAugDcQ9BOyZUgUyNJJvBO2xkDK8OjyOPALiYzs+lGS8cTU1UADi4QIWmXrcv4w8NrJhSD2Gm3Qz2MTGm0AA8gAjXw0DxVOpTWBGeBJVAFZ40aFONI7b7A6DgyZoH5-P6kyGdGHwxGoZGo9GY7G4-HUtCtB5HX6U6CIfYEjJVFCgFzMaIpTmoVq8-l-C5GF5vD4yol8hWwyZgADWFP50kpRq4fMmqEuPnNP2kBG4Y3QkwgLhAUP8KCCoQi8CiMXiwESyRSs1UqAANFo0FQI6GhBGFEoVPwI4YjPGrPNuYQxvBNlVFHUUgApADK0IAclUYkYUHVBQUUk6XYyALZgZ4pOidHp0KptjsFbvQApVZBgFs0OVyn4Aehnc1mACJQ4v5mGl6GqIuw8v+Kv17uyEJt4eo5R90uE8oVzuV2ul6mL4vLPAT4-5vMgA)